# nested binding WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, nested

I'm writing a tool that automatically generate code. This tool generates code for a XAML (WPF) me this way. How can I solve this problem in a situation like that have nested Binding?

i received the error that : System.windows.data.binding does not have a content property .

Pls help me :)

```
    <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:assembly="http://www.vakifbank.com/windows/usercontrols" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:assembly0="http://www.vakifbank.com/windows/commands">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="442" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="376*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <assembly:UComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DtoVergiTuru.VergiTurKodu}" DisplayMemberPath="Code, Description" ParameterGroupCode="VRGVergiTurKodlari" ValueMemberPath="Code" SortMemberPath="Code" Caption="Vergi Tür Kodu" IsRequiredForRead="True" Script="{x:Null}" BehaviourType="Key" Margin="8,2.5,22,2.5">
    <assembly:UComboBox.VisibleColumns>
      <Binding>
        <Binding Path="CmbColumnCollectionVergiTur" />
      </Binding>
    </assembly:UComboBox.VisibleColumns>
    <assembly:UComboBox.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Gesture="Return" Modifiers="" Key="Return">
        <KeyBinding.Command>
          <assembly0:DelegateCommand />
        </KeyBinding.Command>
      </KeyBinding>
    </assembly:UComboBox.InputBindings>
  </assembly:UComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: problem is multiple binding . as
Binding>
        <Binding Path="CmbColumnCollectionVergiTur" />
      </Binding>**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <Binding Path="CmbColumnCollectionVergiTur">

  </Binding>
```

Or

```
  <Binding>
     <Binding.Path>CmbColumnCollectionVergiTur</Binding.Path>
  </Binding>
```

For multiBinding, the syntax should be

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}"
              >
  <Binding Path="CmbColumnCollectionVergiTur"/>
  <Binding Path="XYZProperty"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: I do not write the XAML code. Tool automatically generates. How can i solve the problem?

Comment: multibinding syntax is in my updated answer... you will have to share your tool code where you analyse the multibinding and create node for it