# Bind Nested Field to devexpress Grid column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I have a Property which is a nested object in ViewModel and I am creating a CollectionViewSource in view and binding to that property. (obj is the object)

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding obj.myObjs}" x:Key="MyObjView" >
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" Direction="Ascending"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

and then Binding this view to the grid

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyObjView}}" SelectedItem="{Binding myObj1}">

  <dxg:GridColumn Header="All" FieldName="Disc"/>
  <dxg:GridColumn Header="Adj" FieldName="Adjust"/>
 <dxg:GridColumn Header="Name" FieldName="Acct.Name"/>
 </dxg:GridControl>
```

But now the third column is not showing any data. I think because the FieldName do not go into the nesting so I tried using DisplayMemberBinding

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Acct.Name}" />
```

This is also not working. I want to know how to bind the grid column to that nested property?

Comment: check this link , also answer given already https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B205152

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to [the DisplayMemberBinding property documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_Bindingtopic) you should use the following format when using the DisplayMemberBinding:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Acc.Name}"/>
```

Comment: @SoftDev there are no any hints in my answer related to  the datasets ... the `RowData.Row` just the path to an object in a data source that corresponds to the current row. Have you ever tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need `Mode=OneWay` (assuming they aren't allowed to change the account name in the header) in the binding.

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Acct.Name, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: The Acct.Name is already initialized upon creation of the page and isn't recreated after right?

Comment: This other thread might help as well it looks like there are deeper problems than I thought. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519340/nested-binding-wpf